# String Conversion in C++

Tags: c++, string

I was trying to convert every A to Q. then B to W and C to E.

I arrived with this code but it doesn't work. I'm very new to c++ so I really appreciate your help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void convert(string& s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (i = 'A')
        {
            s[i] = 'Q';
        }
        else if (i = 'B')
        {
            s[i] = 'W';
        }
        else if (i = 'C')
        {
            s[i] = 'E';
        }
    }

}
int main()
{
string s;
cout << "enter string" << endl;
getline(cin, s);
convert(s);
cout << s;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Got it! it works now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic novice mistake of `=` and `==`. The former is the assignment operator while the latter checks equality.

Replace all the `=` in the `if` statements by `==`. Also, the `i` in the `if` statements should be replaced by `s[i]`. So your code will be:

```
if (s[i] == 'A')
  ....
```

Enabling more warnings on your compiler will warn your against this.

Comment: and also i with s[i] in conditions.